# The name 'XFile' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument. Try correcting the name to an existing type, or defining a type named 'XFile'

Tags: flutter, dart, issuu

[here is the issue (https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0zPF.png)

I have tried to run flutter clean and flutter pub get but no changes I don't know what causing this issue.
I will appreciate your help guys.

Comment: What version of dart are you running?

Comment: If you are using image_picker or any other package which is using XFile type, make sure to import it in the file - import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this please:

```
chooseFile() async {
    final chosenFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    
    if(chosenFile != null) {
      return chosenFile.path;
    }
  }
```

If it does not work could you please show me the code you've tried before and explain the desired results.